# JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parse-error

I'm trying to send some data into a JSON object, and then into a cookie. But I'm getting this error when im trying to parse it: "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string".

Here is the code causing the error:

```
function checkCookies() {
    var message;

    if(document.cookie) {
        var iCookie = document.cookie.split('=');
        console.log(iCookie);
        var iObject = JSON.parse(iCookie[1]);

        message = "Cookie finnes: " + iObject.word;
    } else {
        message = "Fant ikke cookie.";
    }
    $("#sectSavedWord").html(message);
}
```

And this is the code where I'm trying to create the cookie:

```
$("#btnSaveWords").click(function(){
        var finalWord = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            finalWord += word[i];
        }

        document.cookie = "info=" + JSON.stringify({"word": finalWord}) + ";expires=" + getExpireDate(7);
        document.location = "oppgave1_2.html";
    });
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I have tried getting this to work for days now. I have used this syntax (or at least something very similar) earlier, and it has worked earlier..

Comment: finalWord is supposed to be a string, not an array. It's getting its content from the word-array, which is based on another array containing the alphabet. (var alphabet = ["a","b","c".... and so on..).. So sample data could be: "HEY!" or "LOREM IPSUM".

Comment: And are you sure there are no other cookies set! You really need to add in other logic!

Answer (score 1):

Your split value `iCookie[1]` will have `;expires` in the string

```
document.cookie = "info=" + JSON.stringify({"word": finalWord}) + ";expires=" + getExpireDate(7);
```

This is causig issue in parsing

```
    var iCookie = document.cookie.split('=');
    console.log(iCookie);
    var iObject = JSON.parse(iCookie[1]);
```

Comment: AKA, find a getCookie method and use that to get the value. MDN is a good place to look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie